# Anaconda vs. IBM Watson Studio

Tags: python, anaconda, cloud, ibm-watson, watson-studio

When running code in Anaconda or IBM Watson Studio, is Anaconda and IBM Watson Studio using your local device’s RAM or are they running the code in the “cloud” servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. Watson Studio Desktop uses the resources of your computer, and also an Anaconda installation on your computer.

Watson Studio on Cloud (dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com) runs your code in the IBM Cloud. The browser renders the result on your screen, using your computer's resources only for that.

Watson Studio Local can be installed by others in their data centers. Then your code would be running in that data center.

---

If you have installed Anaconda locally on your computer, your code will typically run on your computer. Unless you explicitly write code that sends requests elsewhere, for example to call Watson APIs in the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

What services or dependencies you use in Anaconda? I think IBM Watson Studio use the cloud server. With the local dependencies Anaconda will choose the local but if they uses some external service on cloud like AWS or Azure , etc ... they will use cloud too.

Comment: I am just running my own Python code that I have written in Anaconda and IBM Watson Studio. If IBM Watson Studio uses the cloud server, does that mean if I have a very large dataset or my code involves a lot of calculations, IBM Watson Studio will run faster than Anaconda? Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, because IBM Watson use the individual server so you just wait IBM response the result but in Anaconda they use local server so it depend on your machine and your local dependencies.